# Partial sum of a vector

Tags: matlab

For a vector `v` (e.g. `v=[1,2,3,4,5]`), and two index vectors (e.g. `a=[1,1,1,2,3]` and `b=[3,4,5,5,5]`, with all `a(i)<b(i)`), I would like to construct `w=sum(v(a:b))`, which gives the values

```
w = zeros(length(a),1);
for i = 1:length(a)
    w(i)=sum(v(a(i):b(i)));
end
```

It is slow when `length(a)` is large. Can I compute `w` without the `for` loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes! The `n`th element of `cumsum(v)` is the sum of the first `n` elements in `v`, so just take that and subtract the sum of the elements that you don't want to include:

```
v=[1,2,3,4,5]
a=[1,1,1,2,3]
b=[3,4,5,5,5]

C=cumsum(v)
C(b)-C(a)+v(a)

%// or alternatively
C=cumsum([0 v])
C(b+1)-C(a)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works, but it is of course much less readable:

```
% assume v is a column vector 
units = 1:length(v); units = units'; %units is a column vector
units_matrix = repmat(units, [1 length(a)]);
a_matrix = repmat(a, [length(v) 1]); % assuming a is is a row vector
b_matrix = repmat(b, [length(v) 1]);
weights = (units_matrix>=a_matrix) & (units_matrix<=b_matrix);

v_matrix = repmat(v, [1 length(a)]);
w = sum(v_matrix.*weights);
```

Explanation:

- `v_matrix` contains copies of `v`. The summation will be done along
  the column, so we need to prepare the other needed information in
  vectorized form. `units_matrix` contains the indexes in `v` along the
  columns. The columns are identical. `a_matrix` and `b_matrix`, in
  each of their column, contains the indexes that are relevant for each
  partial summation. All rows are identical. `weights` is a logical
  matrix where, for each column, the indexes contained in
  `units_matrix` between the corresponding `a` and `b` are 1 (true),
  and the rest is 0. The element-wise multiplication thus filters the
  "right" values, and all the indexes outside the range (again, for
  each different column) is multiplied by zero. `w` is then he result
  of the `sum` function, i.e. a row vector (every column of the
  "filtered" matrix is summed).

Comment: I see. I have also thought about constructing a indictor matrix (your weights matrix) and you provide me a way to do that, thank you. Although storage is not the issue for my problem, it seems that David's suggestion is simpler (and also faster?).

Comment: David's solution is of course simpler and better, since `cumsum` is directly implemented (it must do something similar to my code, but it is precompiled, hence much faster). I simply could not remember the function.